# Thread return value is inconsistent with expected output

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm working on a project that requires somewhat similar functionality to the program below so I've tried to create a simpler program to debug my larger program. The threads I'm creating are returning values that are inconsistent with their expected output but their return values are not random. It almost seems like the threads are returning the values from other threads or that the variable they are returned to ("tmp") is updating.

The expected output should be...

0 1

1 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct Numbers {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void *go(void* param)
{
    struct Numbers* nums = (struct Numbers*) param;
    int sum = nums -> x + nums -> y;

    return (void*) sum;
}

int main()
{
    int result[2][2];
    int tmp;

    pthread_t thread[2][2];

    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            struct Numbers nums;
            nums.x = i;
            nums.y = j;

            pthread_create(&thread[i][j], NULL, go, &nums);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            pthread_join(thread[i][j], (void*) &tmp);
            result[i][j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider the lifetime of `nums` compared to when threads might try to access it.

Comment: Do you garantee that `nums`, won't get rewritten for all the thread calls ?

Comment: @GManNickG I had a perfect "Ohhhhh" moment. So is my only option to prepare all of the data before the threads are created(outside of the nested for-loop) or is there a better option?

Comment: You just need to reserve space outside of the nested loops: `struct Numbers nums[2][2];` You can fill in the data inside the loops. The other alternative is to use dynamic memory allocation, i.e. `malloc`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help guys. I think I can take it from here.

Comment: Additionally, `(void*) &tmp` is ***very wrong***; you really want a `void**` (i.e. pointer to a variable whose type is `void*`), and `pthread_join` treats this as a `void**` and will try to write a `void*` there, and sometimes a `void*` is bigger than an `int` so it overflows `tmp`. (E.g. Windows is one of those platforms, however you probably aren't using pthreads on Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the address of a variable that probably won't exist once the thread begins executing, or at least will be seen by multiple threads, or is a data race as one thread writes it while the others read it.

A general solution is to dynamically allocate both the arguments and results of your thread, and let the caller and thread communicate that way.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct threadargs {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct threadresults {
    int sum;
    int product;
};

void* threadfunc(void* args_void) {
    // Get thread args in usable type.
    struct threadargs* args = args_void;
    struct threadresults* results = NULL;

    //Compute.
    int sum = args->x + args->y;
    int product = args->x * args->y;

    // Return the result.    
    results = malloc(sizeof(*results));
    results->sum = sum;
    results->product = product;

    free(args);
    return results;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[2][2];
    struct threadresults* results[2][2] = {0};

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0;i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            struct threadargs* args = malloc(sizeof(*args));
            args->x = i;
            args->y = j;

            pthread_create(&thread[i][j], NULL, threadfunc, args);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            void* result;
            pthread_join(thread[i][j], &result);
            results[i][j] = result;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("sum: %d\tproduct: %d\n",
                   results[i][j]->sum, results[i][j]->product);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            free(results[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```